# Python Virtual Env OS PATH Issue

Tags: python, cross-platform

I created a virtual env using venv (Python 3.xx).

There, I installed only a few packages:

[image]

I have one Python Script that reads the files in a given directory and manipulate their data using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = os.getcwd()+'\Ph3_Charts'+'\\'

print(path)

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

days_range = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

dataframes = []
count = 0

for i in days_range:

    try:

        print(i,count)

        dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(path+i, sheet_name = "Issues Jira", index_col=0))

        count += 1

    except:
        pass
```

The problem seems to be with the variable `path`, as the program breaks when it tries to append some data frames from each of the listed files.

[image]

However, the red marked passage above shows the path just fine... The strangest thing is that when I run this program locally, the iteration works ok.

Any guesses why this is happening please?

Comment: Use raw strings when you want backslashes to be literal -- or double them up, to be escaped.

Comment: That said, it's not obvious to me what you're describing as the program "breaking". Can you spell out a little more what it's doing that's wrong? Nothing about the output shown is obviously broken to me as a reader who doesn't know what you're _expecting_ the code to do instead.

Comment: BTW -- it's always preferred to copy-and-paste text instead of providing screenshots; you _can_ copy text from a Windows cmd.exe window, it just takes a little doing. See also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: (...also, is there any particular reason you believe this problem to be virtualenv-related, or to otherwise have anything to do with which libraries are or aren't installed?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes, because when i run this exactly script in the regular environment, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the issue is that you're forcing the script to use the backslash `\` as [the path separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010992/how-to-use-directory-separator-in-both-linux-and-windows-in-python). Your remote system uses Linux whereas you're using Windows locally. Unlike Windows, Linux and macOS systems [prefer to use the forward slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425343/python-and-different-operating-systems/425403) for separating directories in a system path. That's why the difference.

Below is a properly [platform independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform_software) implementation that avoids such needless specificity:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

# Get CWD
CWD = os.getcwd()

# Join CWD with `Ph3_Charts` folder
PH3_CHART_PATH = os.path.join(CWD, 'Ph3_Charts') 

print("PH3 chart path: '"+PH3_CHART_PATH+"'")

days_range = [f for f in listdir(PH3_CHART_PATH) if isfile(join(PH3_CHART_PATH, f))]

dataframes = []
count = 0

for i in days_range:

    try:

        print(i,count)

        dataframes.append(pd.read_excel(PH3_CHART_PATH+i, sheet_name = "Issues Jira", index_col=0))

        count += 1

    except Exception as e: # catch *all* exceptions
        print(e) # print it out
```

This solution works with or without the `venv` features you discussed. Please see the file diff [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/cpTIfAiq) (comparison of differences between your version and the above code).

Comment: thanks. it worked now... i just had to install one more package (openpyxl)